# Unreal 4 illegal reference to non-static member

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to access a variable from a separate class, and I am getting an error.

```
    if (bSprinting){

        UPlayerPawnMovementComponent::movementSpeedMultiplier = 500.0f;
}
```

where the error comes from the movementSpeedMultiplier which when I hover over says: a non static reference must be relative to a specific object.

the variable in question is this one here:

```
public:
virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction *ThisTickFunction) override;

float movementSpeedMultiplier = 150.0f;
```

I know this doesn't work, I'm just totally stumped at how to make the variable editable in both classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To use `movementSpeedMultiplier` you need an instance of `UPlayerPawnMovementComponent`

Comment: ***I'm just totally stumped at how to make the variable editable in both classes.*** Maybe its time to concentrate on learning `c++` before you try to modify a complex `c++` game engine.

Comment: Unfortunately, learning C++ by trial and error does not work all too well. You should learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about [static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).
A skimmed down version of your problem might look like this:

```
struct A{
   float movementSpeedMultiplier;
};

int main(){
  //error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘A::movementSpeedMultiplier’
  A::movementSpeedMultiplier = 500.0f;
}
```

Setting the data member to static, will allow you to access the member without an instantiation.

```
struct A{
   static float movementSpeedMultiplier;
};
float A::movementSpeedMultiplier;

int main(){

  //compiles
  A::movementSpeedMultiplier = 500.0f;
}
```